# How to create view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this data.

```
ID        UserID        Grade
1           1             A
2           1             A
3           1             a
4           1             a
5           1             b
6           1             C
7           1             c
8           1             b
9           2             b
10          2             C
11          1             b
12          2             A
```

I want to create view for this result.

```
RunningNumber UserID         Result         Count
1                1             a              4
2                1             b              1
3                1             c              2
4                1             b              2
5                2             b              1
6                2             c              1
7                2             a              1
```

The result will count column Grade (case insensitive) and must be group by UserID.

I try to use below.

```
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER (ORDER BY Grade) AS RunningNumber , 
       UserID, Grade, COUNT(ID) AS Count 
        FROM Table1
      GROUP BY UserID,Grade;
```

But It's not my results. I want count by select Grade [order by id]. If Grade of next record is the same with current record, Count will be +1. But if not, it will be new record.

Ex. from my data.

```
   userID=1 Grade=A ==> record 1 : userID=1 result=a count=1
   userID=1 Grade=A ==> record 1 : userID=1 result=a count=2
   userID=1 Grade=a ==> record 1 : userID=1 result=a count=3
   userID=1 Grade=a ==> record 1 : userID=1 result=a count=4
   userID=1 Grade=b ==> record 2 : userID=1 result=b count=1
   userID=1 Grade=C ==> record 3 : userID=1 result=c count=1
   userID=1 Grade=c ==> record 3 : userID=1 result=c count=2
   userID=1 Grade=b ==> record 4 : userID=1 result=b count=1
   userID=2 Grade=b ==> record 5 : userID=2 result=b count=1
   userID=2 Grade=C ==> record 6 : userID=2 result=c count=1
   userID=1 Grade=b ==> record 4 : userID=1 result=b count=2
   userID=2 Grade=A ==> record 7 : userID=2 result=a count=1
```

Comment: Which are the results you want?  The table in the middle ("this result") or the example at the end?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you just want to include `userid` in the `row_number()` to get your desired output:

```
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UserId, Grade) AS RunningNumber, 
         UserID, Grade, COUNT(ID) AS Count 
  FROM Table1
  GROUP BY UserID, Grade
  ORDER BY UserID, Grade;
```